# IBM Worklight 6.0 - WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition always return timeout

Tags: android, gps, wifi, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I'm building an application on worklight 6.0 and I'm trying to implement geolocation.

The method `WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition` always returns

> {"code":3,"message":"Position retrieval timed out."}

I followed these steps:

1. Created a new worklight project
2. Placed this code in my javascript file:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit() {
       WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(positive, negative, {
           timeout : 30000,
           enableHighAccuracy: true,
           maximumAge:15000
       }); 
   }

   function positive(data) {   
       WL.Logger.debug("bbbbbbbbbbb2" + JSON.stringify(data));
   }

   function negativa(data) {
           WL.Logger.debug("aaaaaaaaaaaa" + JSON.stringify(data));
   }
   ```
3. add an android environment
4. add these two permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
5. run the app on a samsung s2 with wifi and gps on

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also add to the AndroidManifest.xml the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And make sure this is there as well:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

Did you try with a higher timeout value?

Comment: i added this permissions and put the timeout to 120 seconds, and i still receiving the timeout message.

Comment: Also check in Android check in settings -> Location services that you have enabled Use wireless networks and I have had to enable also Location and Google search...

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](http://gregavola.com/post/37837850898/using-native-geolocation-in-phonegap-for-android) for more information.

Instead of doing:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win, fail, opts);
```

You can do this:

```
var geo = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/geolocation');
geo.getCurrentPosition(win, fail,opts);
```

Turns out you have to call the native module of Cordova to make this work without rebooting. You probably solved this or forgot, but may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue also and it was because I was using the WL API before mobile device Geo was ready.

In my case I copied the code from google maps examples code and it initializes everything with:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap)
```

And then in initializeMap() method is where I tried to use the WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition method.

You must call the initializeMap method in the wlCommonInit() method, not in a "windows load event listener", this way the call to WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition() will be done when the device GEO is ready.

Also check in Android check in settings -> Location services that you have enabled Use wireless networks and I have had to enable also Location and Google search...